# Laravel Socialite Access Token And Token

Tags: php, laravel, api, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I need help about laravel socialite.
I use google service to pre-autheticate my app.

```
Socialite::driver('google')->user()->token
```

Is the above token equal to the Google access token?

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is the access token. socialite  uses authorization code to retrieve accesstoken.

If you want to verify , do like this

```
$token = Socialite::driver('google')->user()->token
$user = Socialite::driver('google')->userFromToken($token);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Laravel Socialite docs:

`Socialite::driver('google')->user()` returns your user object/model. So, `Socialite::driver('google')->user()->token` returns the token on your user model.

> Unless you stored the google access token on your user model, this
>   is not the Google access token